# What is the interval of definition of a solution of an ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't understand this question.

Verify that the indicated function $y=\phi(x)$ is an explicit solution of the given ODE. Consider $\phi$ simply as a function, to give its domain. Then by considering $\phi$ as a solution of the ODE, give at least one interval $I$ of definition.

The answer key gives the largest domain of function as  $[2, \infty)$ and largest interval  of definition for solution is $(2, \infty)$

**What does *interval of definition* mean?**

Answer (score 3):

An interval of definition of a solution is any (open) interval on which it is defined. For example: the problem $y'=y^2$, $y(0)=1$, has solution $y(t)=1/(1-t)$. This solution is defined on the interval $(-1/2,1/3)$, so we can say this is an interval of definition of solution. It's not the largest such: the largest interval of definition is $(-\infty,1)$.

Another example: $y(t)=\sqrt{t}$ satisfies the ODE $y'=1/(2y)$. Although the domain of square root is $[0,\infty)$, when it is considered as a solution of this ODE, the interval of definition is $(0,\infty)$. At $t=0$ the ODE does not make sense, so it would not be correct to say that $y$ satisfies the ODE there. And generally,  ODEs are considered on open intervals only.

Also, I'd expect the book you are using to define the term *interval of definition* the first time it appears.

Comment: For $y(t)=1/(t-1)$ why wouldn't the interval be $(-\infty,1)\cup (1,\infty)$? Shouldn't it be anything that does not make the denominator 0?

Comment: @Celeritas That set is not an interval at all, so it can't be an interval of definition. An open interval is something of the form $(a,b)$.

Comment: Oh so you could say $(-\infty, 1)$ or $(1, \infty)$ just not both?

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind those are essentially different solutions. Solving an ODE is a continuous process of following the direction that it prescribes. When a solution jumps off into infinity as $x\to 1^-$, that's the end of it; what begins for $x>1$ is another solution.