# Find interval where function is defined

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Say we have the separable DE $$\frac{dy}{dx} = (1-2x)y^2, y(0) = -\frac{1}{6}$$ with explicit solution $$y = \frac{1}{x^2-x-6} = \frac{1}{(x+2)(x-3)}$$
Why is it that the interval, where the solution is defined, is said to be only $$-2<x<3$$ and not $$ I = \left\{-\infty<x<\infty | x \neq -2, 3\right\} $$,
since clearly $y$ is defined on $x>3$ and $x<-2$ as well?

Comment: I presume that in your problem has been given also some initial condition. What is it?

Comment: It could possibly be defined, except that we would say it has singularities at the point $-2$ and $3$, which is to say it blows up at those points.

Comment: @RobertZ Added condition to OP.

Comment: @Lozansky So $x_0=0\in (-2,3)$. Now see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in your problem is given also a condition like $y(x_0)=y_0$ with $x_0\not=-2,3$ then 
$$y(x) = \frac{1}{x^2-x-6} = \frac{1}{(x+2)(x-3)}$$
is a solution defined in $(-2,3)$ if $x_0\in (-2,3)$. However it is defined in $(3,+\infty)$ if $x_0\in (3,+\infty)$ and, similarly it is defined in $(-\infty,-2)$ if $x_0\in (-\infty,-2)$.

Usually by definition a solution of an ODE is defined in a interval (which is connected). Take a look also here: [What is the interval of definition of a solution of an ODE?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/923246/what-is-the-interval-of-definition-of-a-solution-of-an-ode)

Comment: Okay, didn't know it had to be a connected set. Thank you.